# SSRS Report builder access issue in Custom Authentication

Tags: sql-server, authentication, reporting-services

I am facing issues while connecting Reporting Services using Report Builder desktop application from client.

My Environment:

1. > SQL Server Reporting Services 2016
2. > Report builder Latest based on clickonce from client machines
3. > SQL Server Analysis Services Tabular Mode 2016 -

> Both my SSRS and Analysis services cube are on same Windows server 2012

Authentication type : CUSTOM

Scenario:
I have enabled Custom Authentication on Reporting Services using CustomAuthentication code. Custom Authentication works fine to connect Report Server. I have role based security setup in Analysis Services 2016 and for custom Authentication Row Level Security is working fine based on CUSTOMDATA parameter.

Now I require Report builder to connect my Reporting Services to do report authoring. In this scenario Report builder successfully does custom authentication and connects to report server but during Data Source connection It again tries to connect SSAS cube from client and it fails. I followed steps in configuring Report Builder access as here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/configure-report-builder-access

Any help in this regard will be great.

Answer (score 1):

Report authoring with ReportBuilder requires a direct connection from the ReportBuilder client to the data source.  See eg

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2009/12/03/report-builder-and-firewalls/

Comment: In my scenario both my client and server are on same network but there is no domain setup... In such a case while opening report builder first check is to connect to report server that is successful using custom security and while connecting data source It asks for username and password after providing it fails with login failed but the same user has full access

Comment: This blog written on 2009 is this same holds good on SQL Server 2016?

Comment: I believe so.  ReportBuilder is a stand-alone reporting tool.  You can use it to author and test RDL reports without any Report Server at all.